# Asp.net web controls

Tags: html, asp.net

```
<ucRpt:Report runat="server" ID="ucMS" />
```

Do any one have any Idea what the tag given above do,

can some one provide a link if have one

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the use of a **User Control** in asp.net.
You can find the registration of the user control in the top of the page.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl/Report.ascx" TagName="Report" TagPrefix="ucRpt" %>
```

**Note:** 1. the source in your code will be different.

and then used in page like

```
<ucRpt:Report runat="server" ID="ucMS" />
```

[More Details:](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/)

Answer (score 0):

Its a **Custom ASP.NET Server Control**
This MSDN article will explain it to you in detail: [Developing Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.ASPX)

If you want to know what your particular custom user control, ie, `ucRpt:Report` does, try decompiling it with some open source tools like [Telerik Decompiler](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and view its source.